# Can I hide an Html link using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

It's a simple exercise in which I want to hide a link I put in my Html file.
But make it appear after a timer has run out in my function.

This is the javascript bit
(below is the html bit)

```
var i = 10;
var time;
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
var link = document.getElementById("link");

function MyFunction3() {
    document.getElementById("imageoef").style.visibility="visible";
    link.style.visibility="hidden";

    i--;
    countdown.innerHTML= i;
    time = setTimeout ("MyFunction3();",1000);

    if (i < 1) {
        countdown.innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("imageoef").style.visibility="hidden";
        link.style.visibility="visible";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." id="imageoef" style="visibility:hidden" />
<form method="post">
    <input onclick="MyFunction3();" type="button" value="start download" />
</form>

<div id="countdown">
    <a id="link" href="http://freelanceswitch.com/freelance-freedom/freelance-freedom-2/" >Your download is ready!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the element with the id imageoef?

Comment: should be fixed when it is peer reviewed

Comment: I didn't include it because that one works already, no need to pay attention to that bit.

It is an image in html, which is hidden at first, but appears when the button's pressed. And disappears when the timer has run out. 
I just can't seem to be able to do the same with the link.

Answer (score 5):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="hideLink()" value="Start" />
<p id="timer"></p>
<a id="link" href="">This link is hidden for 10 seconds.</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var timeLeft = 10;
var count;
window.hideLink = function hideLink()
{
  document.getElementById("link").style.visibility = "hidden";
  count = setInterval (decrementTimer, 1000);
  setTimeout (showLink,1000 * timeLeft);
};

function decrementTimer()
{
  timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeLeft + " seconds";
  if(timeLeft <= 0)
  {
    window.clearInterval(count);
    document.getElementById("timer").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

function showLink()
{
  document.getElementById("link").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rPnNr/4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not quite what i'm looking for.
When I press the button, a timer is set off. When the timer has reached zero, i want the link to appear.

Comment: so put the code above in a function to lunch it with a oncleck event

Comment: It may not be immediately apparent but the question is actually about making a countdown timer appear, run from 10 to 0 then make the link reappear at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you have place the javascript in the header section your code may not work. Because you are storing the `countdown and link` element value at the page loading. At that time if your elements has not get loaded to the page your `countdown and link` vars going to be null. better thing is access your elemet after your button click.

```
var i = 10;
var time;
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
var link = document.getElementById("link");

function MyFunction3() {
    countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
    link = document.getElementById("link");

    document.getElementById("imageoef").style.visibility="visible";
    link.style.visibility="hidden";

    i--;
    countdown.innerHTML= i;
    time = setTimeout ("MyFunction3();",1000);

    if (i < 1) {
        countdown.innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("imageoef").style.visibility="hidden";
        link.style.visibility="visible";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because it sets the `countdown` div's `innerHTML` to '', but the link was inside that div, so gets deleted and you can't then make it reappear just by setting its visibility. You could fix it just by putting the link outside of the div in the HTML.

```
<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." id="imageoef" style="visibility:hidden"
/>
<form method="post">
  <input id="myInput" type="button" value="start download" />
</form>
<div id="countdown"> 
</div><a id="link" href="http://freelanceswitch.com/freelance-freedom/freelance-freedom-2/">Your download is ready!</a>
```

While I was at it I altered your script a bit...  ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aE7s9/1))

```
var i = 10,
  time;
function E(id) {return document.getElementById(id) }
E('myInput').onclick = function () {
  E('imageoef').style.visibility = 'visible';
  E('link').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  time = setInterval(function () {
    i--;
    E('countdown').innerHTML = i;
    if (i < 1) {
      clearInterval(time);
      E('countdown').innerHTML = '';
      E('imageoef').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      E('link').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Actually the other changes are all non-essential but some explanation anyway:

- you ideally want 2 functions, not just 1 - the first to trigger the countdown and the second for each time the counter decreases
- `setInterval` is more useful than `setTimeout` here, as it recurs automatically and you don't need to keep setting it; however you do then need to use `clearInterval` to stop the timer. In your original code you were doing nothing to stop the timer so it would just carry on indefinitely (but with the effects hidden).
- I preferred to set `onclick` in javascript rather than having an `onclick` attribute of the html tag. But your original method does also work.

([Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y4SEt/) is your original code with only the necessary changes to make it work.)